# Evaluating $\arctan(a\tan(b)) +\arctan(a \cot(b))$ when $a=0.1$ and $b=30^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

In a paper, I read:

> Given $a = 0.1$ and $b = 30^\circ$, from equation 1 we find that $c = 39^\circ$.
>
> Equation 1 is given as:
> $$c =  \arctan(a\tan(b)) +\arctan(a \cot(b))$$

When using my calculator (MS Excel), I get a value of $13.13^\circ$.

Does anyone calculate the result of the paper (39 degrees) or my result ($13.13^\circ$)?

If the equation in the paper has a typo of some kind, what should the equation be to get the result $c = 39^\circ$?

**Edit**: Below are images from the paper. The Equation in question is equation 12, where $a=k_y/k_x$, $b=\phi$, and $c=\pi \gamma$. Graphical solutions to Eq 12 are shown in Figure 8.

[image]

**next page:**

[image]

**next page:**

[image]

**next page:**

[image]

Comment: With the equation as stated, [Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arctan%28+0.1+tan%2830+pi%2F180%29%29+%2B+arctan%28+0.1+cot%2830+pi+%2F180%29%29) that the answer is $13.13$-ish degrees (about $0.23$ radians). Seeing the paper in question might prove helpful, because this is a very basic error that I'd be surprised reached publication.

Comment: @PrincessEev please see images from the paper in the edit above.

Answer (score -1):

Recall the identity

$$\arctan(x)\pm\arctan(y)=\arctan\left(\frac{x\pm y}{1\mp xy}\right)$$

---

$$\begin{align*}
\arctan(a\tan(b)) + \arctan(a\cot(b)) &= \arctan\left(\frac a{1-a^2} (\tan(b)+\cot(b))\right) \\
&= \arctan\left(\frac{\frac1{10}}{1-\frac1{100}} \left(\frac1{\sqrt3}+\sqrt3\right)\right) \\
&= \arctan\left(\frac{40}{99\sqrt3}\right) \approx 0.229\,\mathrm{rad} \equiv13.13^\circ
\end{align*}$$